# What is the policy regarding homework question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[This](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1627/389) is a good question. Are we obliged to answer it?

Comment: I wouldn't asked if we're obliged to answer, but if we want to answer homework questions in general, and if yes, what restrictions we should impose on them (e.g. minimum amount of effort, ...).

Answer (score 3):

**Good question? Yes.**

The question is clearly formatted and clearly presents the attempts for finding an answer. So, this is a perfectly valid question for the SO in general and SO.Biology in particular.

**Obliged? No.**
Nobody is obliged to answer any questions. If you feel you can answer it -- just go ahead. But SO is a community project and everything is purely volunatarily.

**Restrictions on homework questions**
Referencing to the comment by [Mad Scientist](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/mad-scientist) I see the following options possible:

*Answer proposal*: Every "homework" question is expected to have a suggested answer from the asker, which can be right or wrong, but it should be comprehensive enough to show the presence of some basic knowledge on the topic.

*Staging*:
The answer is given 3-7 days after the question was asked. Given this rule it becomes useful to ask questions for the classes that take place in shorter than a week.