# Homework Policy for FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-questions

**The answer to this question explains how to ask your homework question here on Biology and have it well received by the community**.

Related:

- [What is the policy regarding homework questions?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-the-policy-regarding-homework-question) (Old)
- [Are users only asking for homework help welcome?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/are-users-only-asking-for-homework-help-welcome)

Comment: See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange, http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange (also the faq entries)

Answer (score 13):

## Homework Questions on Bio.SE

Biology.SE can be a great place to get help and advice with university and school assignments, however we ask that you take the time to read through these tips *before* posting your question.

**What is a homework question?**

- A request for help with an assignment
- Asking for help after exam feedback - i.e. "Why was this marked incorrect?"
- A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals

Any question that meets these requirements should be tagged with [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) *in addition to other appropriate tags*.

**What should I do before I ask the question?**

- Research it yourself - even if you try and can't find the answer or understand the concept you need you can then include what you have found out yourself in the question.
- [Search the site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search) to see if something similar has been asked before.

**How should I ask my question?**

- Give full details of the problem.
- Include details of how **you** have attempted to form a solution.  We will not do your homework assignments for you but we will point you in the right direction if you have made the effort to research the topic first.
- Use logical and clear formatting as this will increase your chances of getting an answer. For example, include tasks from your assignment in blockquotes.

Comment: Everyone please **feel free to rip this to shreds** - it's really just a starting point so we can pull bits out, entirely reverse bits of it or add things in.  We should discuss what we want to include or change on Chat :)

Comment: I'd kill the homework tag entirely, but that probably deserves a discussion of it's own. I don't like the formatting the own attempt as code, it's a misuse of that tag. I'm also thinking of setting the requirements for the own effort quite a bit higher than they are now, to avoid becoming a homework-solving service.

Comment: I also don't like the misuse of the code tag, but I do think that a "homework" tag is needed.

Comment: I understand Mad Scientist point. A homework tag is advertising homework questions, but seeing physics.se got 500 homework questions Im not sure you can really avoid them, then I would rather see them tagged correctly than strongly diversified with other tags and questions about research. If too much low-level homework questions come in, you can still raise the off-topic limit. Trial and error imho. I would agree that site is not for explaining how to solve exercises step by step, the questioner should show his solution method and reasoning and at least a unreasonable result :)

Comment: Im not inclined to solve complete exercises for other user here and probably not many other professionals, mostly some nice students who do similar exercises currently during their studies. And a homework tag would help those students to find such questions easily, otherwise getting few attention and then the questioner ask several bad and localized questions due to their misunderstanding\non-solution of the original homework question being off-topic but still not resolved

Comment: We should probably make it clear that questions saying '*do* this question for me' rather than '*help me* with *my attempt*' will be closed straight off

Comment: I'm more inclined to help you if you've displayed alongside your question information showing that you have some understanding of the topic, and just need a nudge in the right direction. This is not a site for other people to do your hw for you though.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @madscientist that effort level needs to be higher.  If it seems pretty clear that the person hasn't so much as wiki'ed the terms they're asking about, I just get frustrated/annoyed.

Comment: Asking users to show their attempt sounds like a good idea, but in practice I see many questions where a multiple choice question is copy/pasted verbatim, and then the person says "I answered (option whatever)". Does that really count as showing your attempts? See http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/question-about-what-the-liver-does-not-do